# Sanity slug validate chars are lowercase

Tags: javascript, sanity

I am building a vue website using sanity as a backend. Instead of rewriting URLS in the router I want to have a pattern in place in sanity where slugs must only be lowercase letters so,

this-is-a-slug-123 would be valid but THIS-is-A-slug-123 would not be valid, I want to do this check as part of the slug validation to stop people being able to save pages with invalid slugs.

Sanity only has the `required` or `custom` validation rules available for the type slug. How can I validate the slug is solely using lowercase chars?

Comment: can't you just toLowerCase() it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could incorporate a custom validation function that checks against a regex:

```js
validation: (Rule) => Rule.required().custom((slug) => {
  if (typeof slug === "undefined") return true
  const regex = /(^[a-z0-9-]+$)/ // Regex pattern goes here
  if (regex.test(slug.current)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return "Invalid slug: Only numbers, lowercase letters, and dashes are permitted." // Error message goes here
  }
}),
```

This would only validate slugs containing lowercase letters, dashes, and numbers. The regex could be elaborated to account for double dashes, etc., but hopefully this is a start.